# Copying other´s site header

Tags: magento-1

Currently I´m using Luma Theme and I want to stick with that but I want to change my header, like fred perry site: https://www.fredperry.com/eu/

But I can´t find the header file to change it

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This magento 1 website not Magento 2.